# React Router - one of two routes

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, react-router

I know the title may be vague, so I'll try to describe my problem as good as I can.

I am doing a WordPress theme and I need to link to both categories and tags pages. Their structure is `/[categories|tags]/item`. Now I need to make a route for those two items only. I tried doing it like this:

```
  <Route path="/category/:slug" component={Archives} />
  <Route path="/tag/:slug" component={Archives} />
```

But with this I have no distinction of wether this is a category or a tag. I dont wan't to go with `<Route path="/:type/:slug" component={Archives} />` because this may get confusing when I'll need to use nested pages. I also don't want to change the url scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use queries to determine what the type is:

```
<Link to={{ pathname: '/category/[slug]', query: { type: 'category' } }} activeClassName="active">Some Link</Link>
```

Then access the queries in your Archives view via:

```
this.props.location.query // you could set up some conditional logic based on type
```

UPDATE: Without changing the url scheme

```
...

<Route path="/category/:slug" component={Archives} />
<Route path="/tag/:slug" component={Archives} />

// Then in Archives component you could do

class Archive extends React.Component {
   ...
   render() {
      const path = this.props.location.pathname;
      const category = path.indexOf('/category/') !== -1;
      const tag = path.indexOf('/tag/') !== -1;
      ... // some logic based on tag and category
      return {
         ...
      }    
   }
}
```

Comment: Your solution adds `?type=category` to the url, and I want to avoid this.

Comment: I used similar solution myself, but yes, using `location.pathname` is the correct way.